# How to create a thread passing a member function of a specified object?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been looking for some information about this issue and researching on the internet, but I didn't find anything that could solve my question.

In summary, I have two classes, the first class is used as an Interface between cameras and the computer. We could call it, `class CCameraInterface`. Second class is used to handle cameras. We could call it `class CMultiCam`.

In the class `CCameraInterface` I create many `CMultiCam` objects as cameras from different transport layers (i.e. USB3.0 GigE ...), and these objects are stored in a `std::vector` called `m_vCamera`.
Although they are the same kind of object, they will do different stuff in the same functions. Hence, I need to identify which object I am calling in a new thread.

```
Class CMultiCamera{
public:
...
SI_32 GetFrames(std::vector<UI_8*>& f_desiredFrame_p);
...
}
```

I tried to use it inside `CCameraInterface`:

```
std::thread* l_thCaptureImages = new std::thread[m_vCameraConfig.size()];
for (int l_index = 0; l_index < m_vCameraConfig.size(); l_index++) {

l_thCaptureImages[l_index] = std::thread(&CGenIMultiCamera::GetFrame, this, l_index, m_vImage);
m_mutexLock.lock();
s_writableAddress++;
m_mutexLock.unlock();
}
```

By this way, I am not calling the function `GetFrame` of a specific object, but just a generic function from a class `CGenIMultiCamera`.

So I tried to run this line instead:

```
l_thCaptureImages[l_index] = std::thread(&CGenIMultiCamera::GetFrames, (this->(m_vCamera.at(l_index)), m_vImage);
```

But I am getting the next compiler error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(249): note: see the reference to create function template instances void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1>(std::tuple<SI_32 (__cdecl CGenIMultiCamera::* )(std::vector<UI_8 *,std::allocator<_Ty>> &),CABSCameraControl *> &,std::integer_sequence<unsigned __int64,0,1>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<SI_32 (__cdecl 
CGenIMultiCamera::* )(std::vector<UI_8 *,std::allocator<unsigned char *>> &),CABSCameraControl *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<SI_32 (__cdecl CGenIMultiCamera::* )(std::vector<UI_8 *,std::allocator<unsigned char *>> &),CABSCameraControl *>>>,
1>              _Ty=UI_8 *
1>          ]
```

How can I solve it?
Thank so much in advance

Comment: That's not the error message. Note that it says "note:" -- that means it's explaining something that it told you earlier or later. The important bit is the part marked "error:". The code you've shown has a mess of unbalanced parentheses, undefined names, and type mismatches, so it's really not possible to guess what's actually wrong, but the approach you've taken will work if you get the calling syntax right. There's no need here for static member functions or lambdas.

Comment: For problems like this, start with an ordinary function call, without creating a thread. Once you've got that to compile (no need to run it), you know all the appropriate names that you need, and you can rewrite the code to call that function from a thread. So, for example, `f(3, my_thing)` would become `std::thread(f, 3, my_thing)` or, if `f` is a member function, `std::thread(&my_class::f, 3, my_thing)`.

Comment: The code that I have written is a piece of code. My entire programm is about 3000 lines. It was just a sample to get a better knowledgement of the code. My entire code was running perfectly, problem has started when i tried to launch theese threads. I have another threads in my programm without any problem because I dont need to identify between objects of the same class. Thank you for your aclaration. Error shown is: error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

Comment: That error message basically means that the compiler couldn't make sense out of the arguments that the program passes to the `std::thread` constructor. Beyond that, it's impossible to say, because, again, there is not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the address of a static member function plus the address of your object.  Then, from this function, you can call the member function you wanted to call in the first place.

Example code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    static void StaticFunc (MyClass *self) { self->MemberFunc (); };
    void MemberFunc () { std::cout << "MemberFunc called\n"; }
};

int main ()
{
    MyClass obj;
    std::thread t (&MyClass::StaticFunc, &obj);
    t.join ();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WHnPlscxF1ebADer)

Pass additional parameters to `MemberFunc` via `StaticFunc` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda:

```
l_thCaptureImages[l_index] = std::thread([this, l_index] {
    GetFrames(m_vCamera.at(l_index)), m_vImage);
});
```

Comment: Ah, that's neater.

Comment: Thanks rustyx, lambda function should be like this:                l_captureImage[l_index] = std::thread([&] {m_vCamera.at(l_index)->GetFrames(m_vImages);});  Because GetFrames is function of an object stored in m_vCameras vector, and m_vImages it's the args. It works almost fine, but right now I have a runtime error. It works fine like 5 seconds, but then chrash. Exception is here:

Comment: static void _Run(_LaunchPad *_Ln) _NOEXCEPT // enforces termination
  { // construct local unique_ptr and call function object within
  _Target _Local(_STD forward<_Target>(_Ln->_MyTarget));
  _Ln->_Release();
  _Execute(*_Local,
   make_integer_sequence<size_t,
    tuple_size<typename _Target::element_type>::value>());
  }
_Execute would be the next line to execute.